# Project portal bombing after installing VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, tfs

I have a working, new installation of Windows Server, Team Foundation Server, SQL Server etc etc working in harmony, everything working great.  Then -- I installed VS2008 Team Suite on the server so that I could use it as a build agent for automated builds/testing.  After that the project portal was bombing out with...

This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.

I'm sure it has something to do with it writing some new entries in web.config or something, I'm not sure.

Comment: Attach a debugger or modify the web.config to show errors, or run it from the local machine.

Comment: try looking into the SharePoint ULS logs for. They will give you better information on what the actual error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install SP1 of Team Suite as well?  I was wondering if it might have something to do with .NET 3.5 SP1 that also gets installed with Team Suite.

I take is this was a WSS 3.0 installation rather than WSS 2.0?

Comment: Yes it's WSS 3.0, I'll try installing SP1, I didn't think of that.  I'll report bakc with further info.

Comment: Seems as I got mixed up with installing 400 components to get this working and that was the trick, many thanks!